# HyperlinkButton to internal source

Tags: silverlight, hyperlink

I have a SilverLight project, in the project I have a PDF document.

How to create a reference to the pdf document so it will open with a click on a HyperlinkButton? What should the build action be on the PDF document?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the trick with HyperlinkButton won't work, because you will navigate relate to silverlight project but not associated web project.

You can use file download. I recomend [Interlink Upload Download](http://interlink.codeplex.com/).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize it would be that complex to refer to a simple file in a Silverlight project. But fair is fair, you cannot expect everything to be straightforward. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps, once its downloaded what do you do with it then?

Answer (score 0):

You should not include it in the Silverlight project.  Instead include it in the associated web project as standard web content. For example if you place it in the web project in a folder called "Documents" then your button will look like:-

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="LaunchPDF" TargetName="_blank" NavigateUri="/Documents/MyDoc.pdf" />
```

Comment: Thanks, also thought about that, but I'd rather have the file in my Silverlight project. Because I want to be able to redistribute the xap file, independent of a web-site.

Comment: @RvG: What are you going to do with it when its in the Xap?  Silverlight can't use PDF content directly>

Comment: The idea was just to show the document, we use PDF files for user documentation. As I wrote before, the idea is that having the document in the XAP project, you will always have a link to it when redistributing the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ICommand:

ViewModel.cs:

```
        private static string _ApplicationUrl;
    public static string ApplicationUrl
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ApplicationUrl == null)
            {
                _ApplicationUrl = Application.Current.Host.Source.GetComponents(UriComponents.Scheme | UriComponents.Host | UriComponents.Port, UriFormat.UriEscaped);
                //_ApplicationUrl = HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Scheme | UriComponents.Host | UriComponents.Port, UriFormat.UriEscaped);
            }
            return _ApplicationUrl;
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand<string> _WebUriCommand;
    public RelayCommand<string> WebUriCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_WebUriCommand == null)
            {
                _WebUriCommand = new RelayCommand<string>((p) => { HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(ApplicationUrl + p), "_blank"); });
            }
            return _WebUriCommand;
        }
    }
```

View.xaml:

```
<HyperlinkButton Command="{Binding WebUriCommand}" CommandParameter="/Documents/MyDoc.pdf" Content="Download"/>
```